# Subdomain for nested resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, subdomain

My rails app is set to use subdomains as described in this RailsCast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

However, right now, paths render like this:

http://organization.domain.com/organizations/1/edit

I have the controllers set up to choose the organization based on the subdomain already, so I'm wondering if there's a way to strip out the /organizations/:id portion of the paths, such that:

```
link_to edit_organization(@organization)
```

goes to http://organization.domain/edit, instead of http://organization.domain/organizations/:id/edit

Since there's going to be many nested resources within organizations (people, donations, etc), it's important that URL's don't end up incredibly long, and that the path generation method remains pretty straightforward.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As you said, if you have many nested resources. You may want to have look at this http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources .
It is undoubtedly a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a route like:

```
resource :organization, :path => ""
```

The will cut down your url to 'http://organization.domain/:id/edit`.

Getting rid of the `:id` is tricky, and I dont think it can be done directly. What I would do is something like:

```
resource :organization, :path => "", :only => [] do
    match "index", :via => :get
    match "new", :via => :get
    match "show", :via => :get, :constraints => {:subdomain => /[a-zA-Z]+/}
    match "edit", :via => :get, :constraints => {:subdomain => /[a-zA-Z]+/}
    match "update", :via => :put, :constraints => {:subdomain => /[a-zA-Z]+/}
    match "create", :via => :post
end
```

Not very DRY, but I think it should work.